# How to handle the last case?

Tags: haskell

> Define a helper function mergers that given all parts of a word, produces a pair of all possible ways to break up the word.  This recursively. The `concat` function might help you.

I can seem to use map and concat to solve this problem. I've solved the first 3 cases which were much easier but cant solve the last one.

```
mergers :: [String] ->[(String,String)]
mergers [] = []
mergers (x:xs)
        | xs ==[] = []
mergers (x:xs:xy)
        | xy ==[] = [(x,xs)]
mergers (x:xs:xy:_) ->
```

The function:
`mergers ["co","nt","ro","ls"]`
should produce all the possible combination of the given strings like

```
[("co","ntrols"),("cont","rols"),("contro","ls")]
```

`mergers ["co","nt"]`
should give

```
[("co","nt")]
```

`mergers ["co"]`
should return an empty list

```
[]
```

Comment: I think you here do not need that much cases in the first place. There are basically three cases you need to write here.

Comment: Why is `("", "controls")` and `("controls", "")` not in the list of the sample result?

Comment: Tbh I dont know. This is my assignment, which is due in almost an hour and Im barely halfway through it. Functional programming isnt my best suit, I've been seeing a lot tutorials and videos but still cant get my head around Haskell.

Comment: hint: take a look at `concat`, `zipWith`, `inits` and `tails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given function will not suffice. Especially since you need to keep track of the items that have passed. We thus probably should use a helper function that keeps track of the items obtained thus far. These items are then put in a concatenated form in the first tuple.

We thus can work with a helper function, like:

```
mergers :: [[a]] -> [([a], [a])]
mergers [] = []
mergers (x:xs) = helper [x] xs
    where helper left right = …
```

Now in the helper function, if the right list is empty, than we can stop to produce a list. If on the other hand the right list is not-empty, we can emit a 2-tuple where we concatenate both the left and the right in the tuple, and add the first item of the `right` list to the `left` if we recurse.

**EDIT**: since you [managed to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364568/how-to-handle-the-last-case/58364656?noredirect=1#comment103085186_58364656), we can here yield the items with:

```
mergers :: [[a]] -> [([a], [a])]
mergers [] = []
mergers (x:xs) = helper [x] xs
    where helper _ [] = []
          helper la ra@(r:rs) = (concat la, concat ra) : helper (la ++ [r]) rs
```

This then yields the expected output:

```
Prelude> mergers ["co","nt","ro","ls"]
[("co","ntrols"),("cont","rols"),("contro","ls")]
Prelude>  mergers ["co","nt"]
[("co","nt")]
Prelude> mergers ["co"]
[]
```

Comment: I'm grateful for the answer sir but I need to make possible combinations of given set of strings like mergers ["co","nt","ro","ls"]  should give  [("co","ntrols"),("cont","rols"),("contro","ls")] while the code you gave produces the following output [("co","nt"),("ro","ls")].

Comment: mergers :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
mergers [] = []
mergers (x:xs)
    | xs==[] =[]
mergers (x:y) = [( filter (/=' ') (unwords [x]) , filter (/=' ') (unwords y))] ++ helper [x] y
    where helper left right
                        | tail right == [] = []
                        | otherwise = [ (filter (/=' ') (unwords left ++ head right) , filter (/=' ')(unwords (tail right))) ] ++ helper ( left ++ [head right]) (tail right)

Comment: Took me quite a few hours, but finally I made it for String Type atleast. I am really grateful the help and inspiration. Might be posting similar questions sir, please do keep a lookout for me. Many respects, Sir.

Comment: @ShahrukhNawaz: you can slightly improve it by replacing `filter (/= ' ') (unwords ...) with `concat ...`, but I think it is indeed, more or less correct :).